# Fixing Unresolved reference: synthetic for import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_add_widget?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to build https://github.com/zacharee/LockscreenWidgets on Ubuntu 18.04 ; so I got the code from git (and removed references as noted in `settings.gradle` and `app/build.gradle`), and tried to build it from via `./gradlew assemble` from the command line, and it failed with:

```
e: /path/to/LockscreenWidgets_git/app/src/main/java/tk/zwander/lockscreenwidgets/activities/AddWidgetActivity.kt: (15, 24): Unresolved reference: synthetic
...
```

This fails on the line:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_add_widget.*
```

Then I downloaded Android Studio 4.0.1, installed SDK 29 there (it got installed to its own subdirectory; did this via Android Studio/File/Settings/Appearance and Behavior/System Settings/Android SDK), replaced the android.jar there as in instructions, and tried again:

[image: screenshot-android-studio]

The funny thing is, if I start typing out the same line, autocomplete finds everything, no problem:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea, what do I have to do in Android Studio, so that this project finds `kotlinx.android.synthetic` (and hopefully builds without error)?

Comment: Tried Build -> Rebuild Project? Or Invalidate caches and restart...